# Connect Rotary Encoder and LCD1602 to RPi3

Tags: hardware, power

I have a RPi3 setup with an LCD1602 for display. Now I want to connect a rotary encoder to the setup to control what is being displayed.
The problem is encoder is 3v and the lcd is 5v. I don't know if I can connect the encoder on the 3v pin while the lcd is on the 5v pin or if I have to use the 5v with a resistor or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason why you can't power more than one device at the same time. From 5V, 3V3, an external voltage supply, or any combination thereof.

You need to ensure that you do not feed more than 3V3 into a Pi GPIO.

That may be a problem for devices you power with more than 3V3 as any device output is likely to be at the input voltage.

You need to check you are only outputting to the 5V LCD, i.e. you are not reading back any LCD data.

Another problem you may have with a 5V LCD is the Pi's 3V3 GPIO may not be able to drive its inputs high.  Typically 0.7 * input voltage is needed by a device to see high.  That would be 3.5V which the Pi can't supply from a GPIO.  In practice the LCD will probably work.

Comment: So I connected it to the 3v pin and it worked fine, I just didn't want to risk damaging any components so I asked first.